# How do I loop through functions with a for loop?

Tags: python, loops

If I have different functions with increasing numbers in their names how do I loop through them? For example:

```
def Func1():
    something something

def Func2():
    something something

def Func3():
    something something
```

can I loop through them with a:

```
for i in range(1,4):
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can put the functions in a list and loop over that:

```
for func in [Func1, Func2, Func3]:
    result = func()
```

Functions are first-class objects in Python, you can create (additional) references to them and call them from whatever reference you have.

Answer (score 7):

You could do:

```
for fn in [Func1, Func2, Func3]:
    fn(arg1)
```